# Error: A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<int>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list temp and call the function List but this error happens

This error happens only after updating flutter

`A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<int>'.`

I guess there is no List though ,,,

How can I fix this ??

```
 List<int> arr = [];
 List<List<int>> temp = [
    [3,4],
    [3,5],
    [4,3],
    [4,4],
    [5,2],
    [5,5],
    [2,3],
    [2,4],
 ];
 arr = chord3(0,temp[2]); // I call chord3 function here


 List chord3(f,List<int> s){ // this is function and error occurs here
    List<int> temp = [];
    temp.add(f);
    temp.add(1);
    return temp;
 }
```

Comment: This error does not happen with me when I run it on dartpad. Maybe you need to return a list from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `int` here:

```
List<int>chord3(f,List<int> s){ // this is function and error occurs here
    List<int> temp = [];
    temp.add(f);
    temp.add(1);
    return temp;
 }
```

You also have this option, same result:

```
 arr = List<int>.from(chord3(0,temp[2]));
```

Comment: I add `<int>` to chord3 as you mensioned it works well thank you very much!!